# In datatables Remove child rows with no data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, datatables

I have a responsive datatable
I'd like to remove all child rows with no data.

The code that produces child rows:

```
details: {
renderer: function ( api, rowIdx ) {
    var data = api.cells( rowIdx, ':hidden' ).eq(0).map( function ( cell ) {
        var header = $( api.column( cell.column ).header() );
        var idx = api.cell( cell ).index();

        if ( header.hasClass( 'control' ) || header.hasClass( 'never' ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        // Use a non-public DT API method to render the data for display
        // This needs to be updated when DT adds a suitable method for
        // this type of data retrieval
        var dtPrivate = api.settings()[0];
        var cellData = dtPrivate.oApi._fnGetCellData(
            dtPrivate, idx.row, idx.column, 'display'
        );
        var title = header.text();
        if ( title ) {
            title = title + ':';
        }

        return '<li class="turnir" data-dtr-index="'+idx.column+'">'+
                '<span class="dtr-title">'+
                    title+
                '</span> '+
                '<span class="dtr-data" id="poin">'+
                    cellData+
                '</span>'+
            '</li>';
    } ).toArray().join('');

    return data ?
        $('<ul class="topnav" data-dtr-index="'+rowIdx+'"/>').append( data ) :
        false;
},
```

How can I skip rows without data. I need the code something like this:

```
$("span.dtr-data:empty").parent().hide();

<li class="turnir" data-dtr-index="6"> 
    <span class="dtr-title">Expences1:</span> 
    <span class="dtr-data"></span> 
</li>
```

Please help

[image]

My code here: [enter link description here](https://atennis.kz/rank/datatable/)

Comment: select the appropriate row in js and use .remove()

Comment: the script written in Javascript.

Comment: The last line of your example is in Jquery. Anyway you could do it with:
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

That's pseudo code to give you an idea of what you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try to skip outputting a new row when there is no data in the first place.

Something along these lines:

```
if (cellData) {
    return '<li class="turnir" data-dtr-index="' + idx.column + '">' +
               '<span class="dtr-title">' + title + '</span> '+
               '<span class="dtr-data" id="poin">' + cellData + '</span>'+
           '</li>';
} else {
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure. I want to skip rows without data. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: Thank you very much. Great solution